# UI / VaadinSession timeout

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm using Vaadin Flow 13 together with Spring Boot. In my 'application.properties' I have specified the following values:

```
vaadin.servlet.heartbeatInterval=5
vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true
vaadin.servlet.closeIdleSessions=true
```

I do not have a `web.xml` or overwritten the Vaadin Servlet (like described [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17632035/configuring-session-timeout)).

In my application I have a view that registers on a Hazelcast event bus in the `onAttach` method. I use ui.access / push to sync Hazelcast with the Vaadin lifecycle and it looks like it is working fine. In the `onDetach` method the listener to Hazelcast is removed. When I now navigate to a different view the listener is removed correctly.

But if I press the refresh button in the browser while my view is open the `onDetach` method is not called and a new `UI` is created. I totally understand that workflow and assumed that I need to take care of the UI / UI-Session timeout to remove the listener. Sadly I have no idea where I can attach a listener to trigger the deregistration of my Hazelcast listener.

I created the following view to debug the lifecycle:

```
@Route(layout = ConcreteAppLayout.class)
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

    protected MainView() {
        setId("main-view-" + counter.incrementAndGet());
        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        add(new Label("MainView"));

        print("A new MainView(" + getId() + ") is created");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(final AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        final Optional<VaadinService> service = getUI()
                 .map(ui -> ui.getSession())
                 .map(s -> s.getService());

        getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.addDetachListener(e -> print("UI of MainView(" + getId() + ") destroyed")));
        service.ifPresent(s -> s.addSessionDestroyListener(e -> print("Session of MainView(" + getId() + ") destroyed")));

        System.out.println("MainView(" + getId() + ") is attached");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach(final DetachEvent detachEvent) {
        print("MainView(" + getId() + ") is detached");
    }

    private void print(final String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

If I open the view and press refresh I receive more or less the following log:

```
MainView(1) is created
MainView(1) is attached

REFRESH OF BROWSER

MainView(2) is created
MainView(2) is attached
```

If I now navigate to a different view I receive

```
MainView(2) is detached
```

`MainView(1)` or its UI is never closed. How can I handle that problem?

Comment: you probably need to implement listeners for route navigation: https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle.html. on the other side i think it does not matter if your eventbus is not unregistered immediately after leaving a vaadin route.

Comment: "MainView(1) or its UI is never closed. How can I handle that problem?", I think never is a wrong word here. It will be cleaned away, but there is a considerable delay (3 heart beats).

Comment: @TatuLund yes, I assumed this. As you can see I defined the heartBeat to "5". But even after 20 min it was not closed...

Comment: @d2k2 it is not important that it happens in case of a refresh immediately. But currently it happens NEVER. That is my main problem. I assumed that if I define the heartbeat to 1 it will be removed after 3 min or so. But no detach listener (view & UI) is called.

Comment: @HendrikEbbers Actually it seems it's defined in seconds, but skip the `servlet`, just try `vaadin.heartbeatInterval=5`

Comment: @Tazavoo that was the problem :) now the UI is destroyed. THX

Answer (score 4):

My problem was the `vaadin.servlet.heartbeatInterval` property in the `application.properties`. Looks like the correct name is `vaadin.heartbeatInterval`. After changing the property name everything works as expected.